# print in a modal-body and jdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following columns in a MySQL database:

> headline, description, place, resume

At the moment I am printing out the `headline` and `description` in a modalbox with the code below. Now I would like to print out `place` and `resume`in the same modalbox.

I thought I could do that with adding this in my javascript, but then I get printed out description three times instead.

```
$("#editBox .modal-body").html(jdata.place);
$("#editBox .modal-body").html(jdata.resume);
```

How can I print out `place` and `resume`?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-data"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
if(jdata){
    console.log("is json");
    $("#editBox").modal().show();
    $("#editBox .modal-title").html(jdata.headline);
    $("#editBox .modal-body").html(jdata.description);
  //$("#editBox .modal-body").html(jdata.place);
  //$("#editBox .modal-body").html(jdata.resume);
}else{
    console.log("not valid json: "+data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was:

```
$("#editBox .modal-body").html(jdata.description + "<br><br>Place: " + jdata.place);
```